# NLME predictions at different effect levels in R

Tags: r, nlme, mixed

I have a simple made-up example of a field plot experiment with 3 locations, 4 blocks within each location, and 8 rates of fertilizer applied to these plots. a response was measured on those plots.

This is the data:

```
#dataframe
loc <- c("Loc1", "Loc2", "Loc3")
block <- c("Block_1", "Block_2", "Block_3", "Block_4")
treat <- as.numeric(c("0","40","80","120","160","200","240","280"))
empty <-expand.grid(treat,  block, loc)
response <- as.numeric(c(7064,  9250,   12306,  13549,  13300,  13973,   
14749,  14086, 7680, 11426, 12874,  12556,  14274,  14289,  15295,  14587, 
8445,   11588,  13223,  13322,  13508,  13616,  13747,  13352, 9454,     
11104,  12462,  13373,  14060,  14576,  14133,  14427, 5463, 8689,  10194,   
11996,  13475, 12544,   12856,  11557, 5251, 7537,  12074,  12438,  12120,   
11312,  9908, 12841, 4643,  7513,   10499,  12423,  12177,  12545,  12876,   
13047, 4992, 9458, 1071,    12104,  13552,  12602,  13210,  14428, 4061, 
3959,   5871,   8016,   9472, 11554,    12525,  12636, 4598, 7717,  7274,    
8476,   9433,   10768,  10275,  8200, 4862, 5727,   6468,   8532,   10662,   
12054,  12227,  12672, 5218, 7878, 8238, 10303, 10331,  13337,  12877,   
11661))
resp.data <- cbind(empty, response)
resp.data <- resp.data[c("Var3", "Var2", "Var1", "response")]
names(resp.data) <- c("loc", "block", "treat", "response")
```

I adjusted a exponential-plateau function with locations and blocks as random effects.

```
#exponential plateau function
expfunc <- function(beta0, beta1, beta2, x){
             y <- beta0 * (1 - exp(-exp(beta1) / 1000 * x + beta2))
             return(y)}

# model fit with blocks and locations as random effects
exp.loc_block <- nlme(response ~ expfunc(beta0, beta1, beta2, treat),
                   data = resp.data,
                   fixed = list(beta0 ~ 1, beta1 ~ 1, beta2 ~ 1),
                   random = list(loc = pdDiag(beta0 + beta1 + beta2 ~ 1),
                                 block = pdDiag(beta0 + beta1 + beta2 ~ 1)),
                   start = c(12000, 3, -1),
                   na.action = na.omit,
                   verbose = F)

summary(exp.loc_block)
```

Now, I want to have the prediction of the response at level 0 (fixed effect).

```
#prediction at population level (fixed effect)
xvals <- with(resp.data,seq(min(treat),max(treat),length.out=100))
pframe <- data.frame(treat=xvals)
pframe$pred.resp.fix <- predict(exp.loc_block,newdata=pframe,level=0)
```

This is working fine so far. Them I get the prediction at the block and location level.

```
#prediction at block nested in location level (random effect)
Loc.names.vector <- unique(resp.data$loc)
block.names.vector <- unique(resp.data$block)
pframe2 <- with(resp.data,data.frame(treat=rep(xvals, 12)))
pframe2$loc <- as.factor(rep(Loc.names.vector, each = 400))
pframe2$block <- as.factor(rep(rep(block.names.vector, each = 100), 3))
pframe2$yield.exp <- predict(exp.loc_block,newdata=pframe2)
```

So, my question is if there is any way for predicting the response at the location level?

Really appreciate any hint.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's returning `NA`, but does `predict(exp.loc_block, newdata = pframe2, level = 0:2)` get you what you want?

Comment: Just tried that one but get the following error message: `Error in predict.nlme(exp.loc_block, newdata = pframe2, level = 0:2) : 
  cannot evaluate groups for desired levels on 'newdata'`

Comment: Hmm, works for me.  The only thing I changed in your code was `Loc.names.vector` to `loc` when making `pframe2` (since `Loc.names.vector` was never defined in your example).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I worked around another solution, and now the prediction at the block nested in location levels worked. So, the question now is how do I get the prediction at the location level. Thanks a lot!